# Ant - Code format issue when deliver shell from windows to unix by scp

Tags: shell, unix, ant, ssh, scp

I deliver a folder which includes a large number of shell scripts to unix using

```
<scp todir="${user.id}:${user.pwd}@${host.name}:${destination}" verbose="true" port="${host.port}" trust="true" failonerror="true">
        <fileset dir="${source.dir}">
            <include name="**" />
            <exclude name=".project"/>
            <exclude name=".svn"/>
            <exclude name="temp"/>
            <exclude name="jsch_build.xml"/>
        </fileset>
    </scp>
```

then I got an error response

> :/bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.

I know this caused by code format. 
One solution is set ff=unix, but i need to handle these scripts one by one. 
And no dos2unix installed on the unix machine.

Is anybody who can help me solve this issue?Thanks!

Comment: You can make use of fixcrlf ant task : [link](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html) to convert your unix script files to unix compatible format.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ANT [fixclrlf](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html) task which can be used to fix the files before copying them to the remote location.

It's also possible to use this as part of a [filterchain](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html).

```
<copy todir="${staging.dir}">
  <fileset dir="${source.dir}">
    <include name="**" />
    <exclude name=".project"/>
    <exclude name=".svn"/>
    <exclude name="temp"/>
    <exclude name="jsch_build.xml"/>
  </fileset>
  <filterchain>
    <fixcrlf eol="lf" eof="remove"/>
  </filterchain>
</copy>

<scp todir="${user.id}:${user.pwd}@${host.name}:${destination}" verbose="true" port="${host.port}" trust="true" failonerror="true">
  <fileset dir="${staging.dir}"/>
</scp>
```